# how to select only one value from more similiar values using mysql order by

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a SQL query which retrieve wall post list

```
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT senderid,post,date FROM ".post_table." WHERE id='".$mydata->id."' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0, 20");
```

This is working good. But I've now a problem:

If a user post 20 post at the same time, then the first list will show only his post. But I want to show 1 post from one user at the first list. So I'm trying to use the below statement:

```
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT senderid,post,date FROM ".post_table." WHERE id='".$mydata->id."' ORDER BY time DESC, DISTINCT(senderid) LIMIT 0, 20");
```

which is not working at all.
please help me how I can do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use distinct in select clause not in where. try

```
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT senderid,post,date FROM ".post_table." WHERE id='".$mydata->id."' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0, 20");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using distinct in a wrong way

```
SELECT DISTINCT senderid,post,date FROM {post_table} WHERE id='{id}' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0, 20;
```